# Do not send shipment mail when shipment is submitted?

Tags: magento2, shipment

**Magento 2.3.3**

When the shipment is created from the admin (see https://i.stack.imgur.com/nII0M.png), a shipment mail is sent out to the customer. I tried searching for that mail sending part in the code in `Magento\Shipping\Controller\Adminhtml\Order\Shipment\Save.php` but wasnt able to find it.

Any idea where the mail is being sent to the customer when the "submit shipment" button is clicked?

Thanks!

Comment: Since the 'Email Copy' button is unchecked in the screenshot, it should not send any shipment email. This means probably you have a custom code written for the shipment email. Try to check if there is any observer written for `sales_order_shipment_save_after` event or similar ones.

Comment: Yes, right, but I need the code anyway, because I want to send the mail at another place. So do you have any idea where I can find the actual code?

Answer (score 0):

Please go to your admin panel.

in the left menu select Stores and under the Settings submenu select Configuration

Under Sales select "Sales Emails"
[image]

Scroll down until you find the "Shipment" sction in here disable it like the image below:

[image]

This should solve your issue ;)

**UPDATE:** Place where email is sent

The code that will send the email is in:
**CLASS:** `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender`

**Path to file:** \vendor\magento\module-sales\Model\Order\Email\Sender\ShipmentSender.php

```
public function send(Shipment $shipment, $forceSyncMode = false)
    {
        $shipment->setSendEmail($this->identityContainer->isEnabled());

        if (!$this->globalConfig->getValue('sales_email/general/async_sending') || $forceSyncMode) {
            $order = $shipment->getOrder();
            $this->identityContainer->setStore($order->getStore());

            $transport = [
                'order' => $order,
                'shipment' => $shipment,
                'comment' => $shipment->getCustomerNoteNotify() ? $shipment->getCustomerNote() : '',
                'billing' => $order->getBillingAddress(),
                'payment_html' => $this->getPaymentHtml($order),
                'store' => $order->getStore(),
                'formattedShippingAddress' => $this->getFormattedShippingAddress($order),
                'formattedBillingAddress' => $this->getFormattedBillingAddress($order),
                'order_data' => [
                    'customer_name' => $order->getCustomerName(),
                    'is_not_virtual' => $order->getIsNotVirtual(),
                    'email_customer_note' => $order->getEmailCustomerNote(),
                    'frontend_status_label' => $order->getFrontendStatusLabel()
                ]
            ];
            $transportObject = new DataObject($transport);

            /**
             * Event argument `transport` is @deprecated. Use `transportObject` instead.
             */
            $this->eventManager->dispatch(
                'email_shipment_set_template_vars_before',
                ['sender' => $this, 'transport' => $transportObject->getData(), 'transportObject' => $transportObject]
            );

            $this->templateContainer->setTemplateVars($transportObject->getData());

            if ($this->checkAndSend($order)) {
                $shipment->setEmailSent(true);
                $this->shipmentResource->saveAttribute($shipment, ['send_email', 'email_sent']);
                return true;
            }
        } else {
            $shipment->setEmailSent(null);
            $this->shipmentResource->saveAttribute($shipment, 'email_sent');
        }

        $this->shipmentResource->saveAttribute($shipment, 'send_email');

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Yes, right, but I need the code anyway, because I want to send the mail at another place. So do you have any idea where I can find the actual code?

Comment: updated my answer with the path / code that sends the shipment email. let me know if you need any further asistance ;) Oh and don't forget to upvote/mark as answer if this solved your problem :)